# Import Project from GitHub into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github, import

I'm working on a Libgdx Projekt and unfortunatly i messed up and so deleted the Projekt in the Package Explorer (without deleting the Project Contents on the disk). When I now try to import my downloaded commit from GitHub Eclipse says "No Projects were found to import" 
How can fix this issue?

[image: Eclipse Import Screen]

Answer (score 0):

With Eclipse Neon, once your project is cloned, use `File > Import projects from filesystem...`. This should detect possible import configurations.